# How to find canplay event in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, html5-video

[image]

I want to add one image till the video is ready to play. 
After page load black screen appears and when video is ready then other screen below the black screen is visible.

For black screen I want to put one image there. In Video tag there is property of "poster" but in iframe "poster" is not working.

And also I want to add listener to detect video is ready to play or not.

Following is my code. Any suggestions please?

```
youtubeLoadVideos : function () {       
    var videos = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube");
    for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        var youtube = videos[i];
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");      
        iframe.setAttribute('poster','/static/images/loading.png'); 
        iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://docs.google.com/a/oprance.com/file/d/" +youtube.id + "/preview");

        // The height and width of the iFrame should be the same as parent
        iframe.style.width = youtube.style.width;
        iframe.style.height = youtube.style.height;
        iframe.style.clear = 'both';
        iframe.style.position = 'absolute';
        youtube.parentNode.appendChild(iframe, youtube);
        //youtube.appendChild(youtube.id);
        iframe.addEventListener("canplay", function() { 
            console.log('-------');
            iframe.setAttribute('poster','/static/images/play_button5.png');    
            videos.style.display = '';  
        });     
    }
}
```

Comment: if the iframe is pointing to a different domain than you can't as you cant access the dom across domains

Comment: @Patrick Evans : then what I can do if I dont want to see that black screen?

Comment: embed the video directly to your page

Comment: @Patrick Evans: I uploaded videos in Google Drive. From Google drive viewer File-> Embed this video : gives one text which is in iframe and src of that is mentioned in code. I am doing this because I want to share video publicly. I tried other option in which I embedded video in <video> tag in that case I am not able to add this publickly published video that is problem of not using <video> tag. Because this <video> tag requires file type like mp3, mp4 etc. But in Google drive uploaded video is not having file type. So I am confused what should I do?